# How to Direct access through the database query to product name , product price and permalink and product photo columns

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

How do I get Direct access through the database query to product name , product price ,permalink , and image url of product  in WordPress WooCommerce ?! 
what's the sql query ?

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wpdb;

$metas = array(
        '_thumbnail_id', '_regular_price'
    );

    foreach ($metas as $i=>$meta_key) {
        $meta_fields[] = 'm' . $i . '.meta_value as ' . $meta_key;
        $meta_joins[] = ' left join ' . $wpdb->postmeta . ' as m' . $i . ' on m' . $i . '.post_id=' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID and m' . $i . '.meta_key="' . $meta_key . '"';
    }
    $request = "SELECT ID, post_title, " .  join(',', $meta_fields) . " FROM $wpdb->posts ";
    $request .=  join(' ', $meta_joins);
    $request .= " WHERE post_status='publish' AND post_type='product' AND $wpdb->posts.post_title like '%sample%'";



$product_details = $wpdb->get_row($request, OBJECT);


if(!empty($product_details)){

    $qry = "SELECT guid FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID=" . $product_details->_thumbnail_id;
    $uri_obj = $wpdb->get_row($qry, OBJECT);
    $product_details->_thumbnail_id = $uri_obj->guid;

}
echo '<pre>';print_r($product_details);exit;
```

Comment: How can i do  the search on this query by product name?

Comment: @حسیناچ . Updated the answer

Comment: How can i get Photo of Product with this query ?

Comment: @حسیناچ Why you are not using default function of WooCommerce? May I know

Comment: Because I want to get information through another software

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I need direct product image  address .

Comment: I saw your answer. But I don't know how  to Combine these two queries In a single Query . please update your code on this question

Comment: @حسیناچ . Updated my answer